# How to clear the entire call stack of the browser on the basis of a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I want to clear my entire call stack of the browser when a certain function gets executed in my React JS code.

Comment: `clear my entire call stack`? What does that even mean?

Comment: i meant certain functions were not executed initially and when i change my state i no longer want them to be executed and thus remove from call stack of the browser

Comment: It seems your understanding of a "call stack" is unusual. I still don't understand what the question is about.

Comment: `throw;` should do it.